# Convert a list into a string, but don't change anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to convert a list like this:

```
old_list = ["abc","abs(1,2)","bla"]
Todo----
new_list = "[abc,abs(1,2),bla]"
```

Is there a smart way to do this?
Maybe with .join and some lambda stuff?

Comment: another but w/ spaces after commas: `str(old_list).replace("'", "")` which might be more readable :ğ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `join` with f-string:

```py
>>> f"[{','.join(old_list)}]"
'[abc,abs(1,2),bla]'
```

You can also create a `lambda` function out of above string join and f-string:

```py
>>> convert = lambda lst: f"[{','.join(lst)}]"
>>> convert(old_list)
'[abc,abs(1,2),bla]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `join`.

> `','.join(old_list)` - Joins the contents of `old_list` with `,` as separator

```
new_list = '['+ ','.join(old_list) +']'
```

```
Output:

new_list = '[abc,abs(1,2),bla]'
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use join operation
Try this

```py
list1 =["a","b"]
string1 = "["+",".join(list1)+"]"

print(string1)
```

Comment: still wrong, output does not contain the square brackets as required by question

Comment: I have executed it twice and it is working for me could you pls tell me what error you are getting

Comment: as you have seen in the question: square brackets are required in the string output but it does not have any square brackets in output. I am not getting error but the output is wrong.

Comment: also, you should never assign variables with built-ins name. you should change `list=` to `my_list`

Comment: you this print instead of old one
print(f" [ {string} ]")

Comment: the above code gives output with unwanted space. output = `[ a,b ]`

Comment: sure  mate i didn't notice it this time next I will rectify it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution for converting lists to str and back to lists:

Convert to string:

```py
>>> import json
>>> new_list = json.dumps(["abc","abs(1,2)","bla"])
>>> new_list
'["abc", "abs(1,2)", "bla"]'
>>> type(new_list)
str
```

Now converting back to list

```py
>>> import json
>>> new_list = '["abc", "abs(1,2)", "bla"]'
>>> type(new_list)
str
>>> old_list = json.loads(new_list)
>>> old_list
['abc', 'abs(1,2)', 'bla']
>>> type(old_list)
list
```

the above is called json format and you can read about the library at [Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json)

Comment: If you look closer, `new_list` of yours doesn't match the expected output...

Comment: Yes I know, just an alternate to simply converting to string. It has more features so I thought recommending it might be good

Answer (score 0):

*Its not exactly what you are looking for*

You can convert the list into a string by typecasting the whole list into string. But the quotation marks will remain if this method is used.

```py
>>> old_list = ["abc","abs(1,2)","bla"]
>>> new_list = str(old_list)
>>> new_list
"['abc', 'abs(1,2)', 'bla']"
```